# Flickering when using neon-animated-pages with Polymer

Tags: animation, polymer, polymer-1.0, flicker, polymer-starter-kit

I searched for this the solution a lot but I couldn't find any post describing the same "flickering" problem.

You can see a GIF [here](http://giphy.com/gifs/3o6Ztmt6dHyTo4zPu8)

**Situation**
I have a website with a menu, using `app-route` as in Polymer Starterkit but enhanced with neon-animated-pages.
If you use the menu (Start, My Card, My Dashboard) there is a smooth transition.

**Problem**
Go to "My Card" and click the enhance card arrow down (tooltip "more info") at the first card.
Now use the menus again and the page transitions are now flickering, as soon as the animation finished. It is like all object are quickly moving somewhere and then back to the position where they should be.

**What I have tried**
I tried to change CSS, as it seems to "re-align" the objects on the page. 
Also I had this problem before when I used javascript to route to another page, but using "a href..." for app-route (as in polymer starterkit), this problem disappeared again.

Anyone have any idea what this can be?

I checked with Chrome, Firefox and IE, seems to be the same everywhere.

Thanks very much for your help!
Kind regards,
Huebiii

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on your site using OS X El Capitan, Chrome 52. Can you provide a screencast/gif of this symptom?

Comment: I have uploaded a gif here: http://giphy.com/gifs/3o6Ztmt6dHyTo4zPu8

You can see at the end of the transitions that the objects are moving to the left. The top search bar seems to be "resizing" horizontally.

Comment: What OS and browser (and versions) are you using?

Comment: Windows 7, Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 m

Comment: I also made a new screenshot: https://img42.com/i7my3+

The screenshot shows how/where the objects move in that "flickering" moment. I took it by using the emulation mode in debug mode in Chrome using iPad screensize. It even stays like this there.

Actually it looks like CSS is somehow getting screwed up by the animation, but I don't understand how - as initially the objects are in the right place.

Comment: Unfortunately this is still persisting - does anyone have an idea how I could resume? Also tipps how to debug an animation would be helpful...the step by step in Chrome doesn't seem to help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found two more sources on github with the same issue and solutions.

1. Apparently only slide left/right animation are affected. Using a different animation should help.
2. Set `Element.prototype.animate = null` before loading the polyfill.

[Flicker after slide animation in neon-animated-pages in Chrome](https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation/issues/205)

[web-animations-next-lite flicker #86](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js/issues/86)